# Difference between Java EE and Java Web

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans

My intent is to learn Java EE so when I start a project in netbeans, I can choose from Java EE and Java Web. The problem is, that I don't fully understand what is the difference between these two and which one to choose. I have some basics on JSP, JSF, Servlets. I guess all server side stuff is enterprise. So what are extra features of Java EE compared to Java Web?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In NetBeans, java web refers to simple java web applications that can run in a light-weight container like Tomcat or Jetty. J2EE is intended to be run in a full Application Server such as Glassfish, and contains java web components, EJBs and JPA ORM. If you're a novice and want to start with easy stuff the JavaWeb applications may be better for you. Here's a write up from NetBeans: https://netbeans.org/kb/trails/java-ee.html

Comment: Well,  I worked with Java on Tomcat but my problem is, I don't fully understand what is the benefit of the EJB. What is the diffence between making an application for Glassfish with EJB and JPA instead of simply doing the same in Tomcat with JSP, JSTL, Servlets, JSF and Hibernate ORM?

Comment: The biggest benefit of working with a full J2EE stack is transaction management. JPA is isolated enough from the rest of J2EE that you can use it alone (backed by hibernate or some other JPA compliant ORM). I have built several large-scale web applications that use just Servlets and JPA in Tomcat and Jetty. Honestly, I find using the full J2EE stack more of a pain than it's worth, even after EJBs were revamped in v3.0.

Answer (score 3):

Both concepts are imprecisely used but ... OK, roughly speaking: Java EE is something broader than Java web. If you intend to use only technologies which a simple web container implementation (e.g. Tomcat) provides, then you're after a Java web project. If you intend to use additional technologies (say EJBs, or other EE technologies) then you need a full blown Java EE server (e.g. JBoss/WildFly). So I guess in your case you just need a Java web project.

For a full list of the Java EE technologies, see here:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/index.html

Comment: Exactly that detail I don't understand well. If JavaEE is JavaWeb+Something what is that Something?